# Como retornar uma consulta do MySql com caracteres específicos dentro de cada celula?

Tags: mysql, select, varchar

Se na minha coluna possui um campo neste formato: `181202272`, (um varchar de 10 caracteres), gostaria de retornar na minha consulta através de um `SELECT` pelo MySql desta forma:

```
18:12:02.272
//Nos dois primeiros caracteres inserir dois pontos, em seguida avança mais dois caracteres e inserir mais :, e antes dos trés últimos inserir um ponto
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boa noite amigo,
Para realizar essa ação basta utilizar o comando `SUBSTR(str, pos, len)` do próprio Mysql, neste comando você deverá colocar a string e as posições de início e fim desejadas. 
Ex:

```
mysql> SELECT SUBSTR('181202272',0,2);
+--------------------------+
| SUBSTR('181202272',0,2)  |
+--------------------------+
| 18                       | 
+--------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Você fará para cada parte da sua string que você deseja segmentar. Em seguida utilizando o comando `CONCAT (string1, string2,…)`você deverá realizar a concatenação desejada.

```
mysql> SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTR('181202272',0,2),':',SUBSTR('181202272',2,2));
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| CONCAT(SUBSTR('181202272',0,2),':',SUBSTR('181202272',2,2))  |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| 18:12                                                        | 
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Realize o `CONCAT` de todos os `SUBSTR` desejados separados pelo caractere que você desejar.

Espero que tenha ajudado.

Abraços.

Referências:
[SUBSTR](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-substr-function.php)
[CONCAT](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-concat-function.php)